# Longest Common Suffix-Prefix

Tags: algorithm

Is there an efficient algorithm to find the longest common suffix and prefix of two different strings? The alphabet size is unbounded.

Formally, let string S = wa and T = bw, where a, b, w are substrings. How to find the longest such w, given S and T?

Comment: There's suffix array and suffix tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Trie tree, it's very useful for common suffix

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer.